# Conditionally returning a custom response object to the client in Wep Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 service that will be deployed across 4 production servers. When a request doesn't pass validation a custom response object is generated and returned to the client.

**A rudimentary example**

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var responseObject = responseGenerator.GetResponseForInvalidModelState(ModelState);
    return Ok(responseObject);
}
```

Currently the responseGenerator is aware of what environment it is in and generates the response accordingly. For example, in development it'll return a lot detail but in production it'll only return a simple failure status.

How can I implement a "switch" that turns details on without requiring a round trip to the database each time?

Due to the nature of our environment using a config file isn't realistic. I've considered using a flag in the database and then caching it at the application layer but environmental constraints make refreshing the cache on all 4 servers very painful.

Comment: You really can't put anything in your web.config?  Seems like the perfect place for it.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF I can put it in the web.config but every time I want to change it I'd have to make the change, check it into source control, fire off the build server, and then deploy it through  our dev environment, then to our test environment, and THEN to production. It's very controlled with a lot of separation of power.

Comment: Isn’t ridiculous that you need to change how software is developed and configured because of over-controlling operations?  I feel your pain, I deal with this as well.  Are you able to add a header to the requests in production?  If so, you would have a message handler that changes the behavior of the service in the presence of a particular header.  So, if you want to debug, can you send requests with something like Postman and add the header?  Or, even a parameter in the query string?

Comment: We discussed the idea of a custom header or query param but unfortunately it's a situation where [many different] vendors are building websites that are going to call this service and the risk of them forgetting to turn it off is pretty high and thus leaking information. The extra detail is ultimately for them so I'm going to focus my energy at other low hanging fruit that'll make things easier for them

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the parameter suggestion and then implementing a token system on the back end. If a Debug token is present in the request the service validates it against the database. If it's a valid and active token it returns the additional detail.

This allows us to control things from our end while keeping things simple for the vendors and only adds that extra round trip to the database during debugging.